# Finding equation of a plane parallel to given vectors which might not necessarily pass through certain points.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the understanding of a certain question.
The question asks

> Find the equation (i.e. the normal form) of the plane parallel to the given vectors $~a = [1 ~~1~~ 1]^T~$ and $~b = [-1~~ 2 ~~1.5]^T~$ containing the point $~p = [0.5~~ 0.7~~ 1]^T~$."

What I did was find the normal vector perpendicular to the plane by finding the cross product of both vectors $~a~$ and $~b~$ and calculated $~n = [-0.5~~ -2.5 ~~3]~$. Now to find the equation of the parallel plane do I use the equation $~n \cdot r = n \cdot p~$?

Or am I completely misunderstanding this?

Comment: Yes, you have exactly the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right basic idea. The equation of the plane is $$-0.5x-2.5y+3z+d=0.$$ Stick in the values $$x=0.5,y=0.7,z=1 $$and solve for $d.$